# Priming a siphon with a pump

Tags: fluid-dynamics

So a simplified version of my question is: Can you make a siphon work if you add a flow of water to the down stream portion of the siphon?

Ill rephrase it another way: The entry of the siphon is in the water of a upper tank, the tube goes up and over a wall and into another tank below the first one. If I add a flow of water to the downstream portion (after the wall before the lower tank) will the siphon start to siphon again?

here is a picture[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you're doing. The siphon is going to want to let water flow until the sump's water level is the same as that of the tank, and you've drawn the two water levels as being at much different heights. Your idea is that the water pump will deliver water from the sump to the tank at exactly the same rate as the siphon is letting water flow from tank to sump? That's not going to work unless you have some electronic water level sensor attached to the tank and some control circuit which can run the pump at exactly the right speed. Seems pretty complicated to me.

Comment: http://engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: so the siphon only goes into the water about an inch or two so when the water gets below that the siphon will stop. my question is, if I loop a part of the flow from the pump back to the siphon will that create a suction again in the siphon?